# Mostrar 2 modales según cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Estoy programando una página web que es una tienda online, tengo que mostrar dos ventanas emergentes, una para si es mayor de edad y otra para aceptar la política de cookies.

El problema es que si entran por primera vez le salen las dos ventanas y se superponen y no queda nada bien.

Es posible hacer una condición que si se van a mostrar las dos ventanas, se muestre primero la de la edad y luego la de cookies?

Lo que estoy haciendo ahora es si son mayores de edad y dicen que si, lo guardo en una cookie, si por lo contrario dicen que no, no pueden acceder al sitio:

```
function getCookie(c_name){
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
  if (c_start == -1){
      c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
  if (c_start == -1){
      c_value = null;
  }else{
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1){
          c_end = c_value.length;
      }
      c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
  return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

if(getCookie('edadVisitante')!="1"){
    $('#laEddad').modal('toggle')
    $('#laEddad').css("display","block");
    //$('#laEddad').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}
function PonerCookie(){
    setCookie('edadVisitante','1',365);
    $('#laEddad').modal('hide');
    $('#laEddad').css("display","none");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Código con Jquery.
    $( "#cookies" ).click(function() {
        $('#resModal').html('&#128532; Lo siento no puedes visitar la página');
    });
})
```

Luego la ventana emergente de la aceptación de cookies, hago lo mismo, una vez la aceptan guardo una cookie para no mostrarle la ventana más:

```
  function readCookie2(c_name){
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1){
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1){
        c_value = null;
    }else{
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1){
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
  }

if(readCookie2('aceptaCookies')!="1"){
    $('#nuevaCookies').modal('toggle')
    //$('#laEddad').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}else{
    $('#nuevaCookies').modal('hide');
    //$('#nuevaCookies').css("display","none");
}
```

La idea como digo es que si tienen que aparecer las dos, que aparezca primero la de la edad y tal como acepten esa que aparezca la de las cookies, es esto posible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que hasta que no acepten la cookie de edad no van a poder avanzar.

Podrias en el document.ready verificar que tenga la cookie de edad, si no la tiene abres ese form. En el guardar de ese form, si respondio que es mayor de edad, abres el de aceptar cookies.

En el mismo document.ready, si ya esta contestado la de edad y no la de aceptar cookies abres el form para aceptar cookies.

Igualmente revisaria la logica, porque por lo que dices el form de edad lo estas guardando como cookie antes de que la persona acepte las cookies.

en el ejemplo que tienes, podrias modificar:

```
function PonerCookie(){
    setCookie('edadVisitante','1',365);
    $('#laEddad').modal('hide');
    $('#laEddad').css("display","none");

    $('#nuevaCookies').modal('toggle'); // agregado que abra el form de aceptar cookies luego de aceptar el de edad
}
```

y reemplazar

```
if(readCookie2('aceptaCookies')!="1"){
    $('#nuevaCookies').modal('toggle')
    //$('#laEddad').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}else{
    $('#nuevaCookies').modal('hide');
    //$('#nuevaCookies').css("display","none");
}

y

if(getCookie('edadVisitante')!="1"){
    $('#laEddad').modal('toggle')
    $('#laEddad').css("display","block");
    //$('#laEddad').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}
```

por

```
if(getCookie('edadVisitante')!="1"){
    $('#laEddad').modal('toggle')
    $('#laEddad').css("display","block");
        //$('#laEddad').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}
else if(readCookie2('aceptaCookies')!="1"){
    $('#nuevaCookies').modal('toggle')
    //$('#laEddad').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}
```

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: perdona Roberto, pero no he entendido a que te refieres con tu respuesta

Comment: Hola @EnzoLeonel gracias por tu respuesta, solucionado de forma brillante! Y bienvenido!